# Pandas update column A in dataframe1 where dataframe1 column2 matches dataframe2 column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
[
  (73, 15, 'update1', 1, 'foo'),
  (63, 64, 'update2', 2, 'bar'),
  (56, 72, 'update3', 3, 'foo'),
],
columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
)
```

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
[
  (73, 15, 'new1', 2, 'foo'),
  (63, 64, 'new2', 3, 'bar'),
  (56, 72, 'new3', 1, 'foo'),
],
columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
)
```

I am looking for a way to join these 2 dataframes on column D and then update the column C of df1 so as to match the value of column C in df2.

Final Result:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
[
  (73, 15, 'new3', 1, 'foo'),
  (63, 64, 'new1', 2, 'bar'),
  (56, 72, 'new2', 3, 'foo'),
],
columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
)
```

Any help is appreciated.

## What I have tried so far?

Run a for loop and update the values in df1 by finding the corresponding value of column c in df2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `map`:

```
df1['C'] = df1.D.map(df2.set_index('D').C)

df1
    A   B     C  D    E
0  73  15  new3  1  foo
1  63  64  new1  2  bar
2  56  72  new2  3  foo
```

where `df2.set_index('D').C` returns the mapping you needed from `D` to `C` in `df2`:

```
df2.set_index('D').C

D
2    new1
3    new2
1    new3
Name: C, dtype: object
```